# Where do I find the all in image adjustment GUI in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, shortcuts, filter, image-format

I am struggling to find the actual way you're supposed to open this window/gui. I imported an image upon creating a new document on photoshop, but it only opened for one image (see picture). Is there any way to open this window in a more conventional and compatible way?

Thanks in advance!
[image: This is the GUI:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Camera Raw window. If you have a RAW file, the image will automatically open in this window. If you have a regular jpg image, you will first have to open the file in Photoshop and then open in Camera Raw by going to "Filter -> Camera Raw Filter"

Comment: This is it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: you can open any image into this editor from the regular working space if you wish to. It can be useful for much more than RAW files. Cmd/Shift/A on Mac, presumably Ctrl/Shift/A for Windows.